# C# Xamarin Android - InputEventReceiver: Input event receiver has already been disposed

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Forms app that contains a MainPage and a picker, like this:

```
    <Picker 
        Title="Picker Title"
        SelectedIndex="{ Binding PickerEl, Mode=TwoWay }" >
        <Picker.Items>
            <x:String>1</x:String>
            <x:String>2</x:String>
            <x:String>3</x:String>
        </Picker.Items>
    </Picker>
```

When I am debugging and click on the picker, and make a selection, I will frequently see this message in the output:

> [InputEventReceiver] Attempted to finish an input event but the input
> event receiver has already been disposed.

Is it anything to worry about? I can't find much info on it, other than that it's probably related to the picker popup being closed on selection.

Thanks!

Comment: the android log is full of messages that look alarming but usually mean nothing

Answer (score 0):

You could try the code with binding like below. It works on my side.

```
public partial class Page25 : ContentPage
{
    public string PickerEl { get; set; }
    public Page25()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PickerEl = "1";
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```